# Codeigniter e-mail special characters

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

I’m trying to send a e-mail with E-mail library using the SMTP protocol and special characters like áéíó. The problem is that the e-mail sends without this special characters even using the UTF-8 config.

I’m using the Amazon SES.

Look the code.

```
   //Libraries
   $ci->load->library('email');
  //Seta gMail
  $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
  $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://";
  $config['smtp_user'] = "user";
  $config['smtp_pass'] = "pass";
  $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
  $config['smtp_timeout'] = 30;  
  $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
  $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
  $config['validate'] = TRUE;
  $config['mailtype'] = "html";
  $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
  $ci->email->initialize($config);
  //Carrega o modelo do e-mail
  $mensagem = $conteudo;
  //Seta variáveis
  $ci->email->from("cool@email.com", $titulo);
  $ci->email->reply_to('cool@email.com', 'New user');
  $ci->email->set_alt_message($conteudo);
  $ci->email->to($email_destino);
  $ci->email->subject($titulo);
  $ci->email->message($mensagem);
  $ci->email->send();
```

Comment: Change your charset to 'quoted-printable'. Reply with the results.

Comment: Hello Matt. The e-mails does not send using the quoted-printable charset.

Answer (score 0):

Simply encode the subject and it will work. The provided string must be plain text / no encoding otherwise it won't work.

This will work :

```
$ci->email->subject(utf8_encode("Special characters : éàî"));
```

This won't work

```
$ci->email->subject(utf8_encode("Special characters : &eacute;&agrave;&icirc;"));
```

For the email's body, unsure all special characters are encoded properly

This will work :

```
$ci->email->message("<p>Special characters : &eacute;&agrave;&icirc;</p>");
```

This won't work

```
$ci->email->message("<p>Special characters : éàî</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of CodeIgniter internal E-mail library is that it is a pain to send a body with non-latin characters. And if it is acceptable to escape some characters of european languages, this is unrealistic to escape a whole text composed exclusively of non-latin characters.

Even if some solutions seem to work you may face a problem of compatibility with some e-mail clients.

A better solution is to embed the PHPMailer library which is far better than the internal CI lib. You could use this [**wrapper for CodeIgniter**](https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer) and set the **Encoding** property to *quoted-printable* with the function `set_encoding($encoding)`.